# DirectAdmin Cron Job not running because cron-user permissions

Tags: magento, cron, sh, centos7, directadmin

I need to run a specific cronjob on my CentOS 7 DirectAdmin install.
All cronjobs are running fine, except a job that needs to import some stuff inside the DB.

That cronjob can not run successful because the cron-user permissions.
User is having SHELL access from DA.

How and where can I edit the cron-user permissions?

I use this crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# | .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# | | .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# | | | .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# | | | | .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# | | | | |
# * * * * * user-name command to be executed

*/5 * * * * root /bin/sh /home/[path-to-magento-install]/public_html/cron.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please add this magento cron under the directadmin user and enable the SHELL access for that user, so that you will not get permission and any other issues with your cron.

Comment: I already added the user inside DirectAdmin. I also user my administrator user for this account, so I do not use the reseller and user level to define users. My administrator user is the only user, that I use. That is also the user that runs this cron. So it should have all access, also SHELL, shouldn't it?